# Recursive function for finding factorial of a number

Tags: c, recursion, decrement

I am getting an output of 24 which is the factorial for 4, but I should be getting the output for 5 factorial which is 120

```
#include <stdio.h>
int factorial(int number){
    if(number==1){
        return number;
    }
    return number*factorial(--number);
}
int main(){
    int a=factorial(5);
    printf("%d",a);
}
```

Comment: It is giving `6` for 4! and `24` for 5! and `120` for 6! Do you see a pattern?

Comment: `warning: operation on ‘number’ may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]`

Comment: yes but i want know why my code is wrong where did i do something wrong if i replace           --number with the number-1 i get the right answer though

Comment: In `number*factorial(--number)` what will be the value used for the *first* `number`? The `number` is decremented at *some time* between the previous sequence point and `--number`. But nobody knows exactly when.

Comment: how come `number` gets replaced by `--number` even before the execution of `--number`

Comment: Because the pre-decrement happens *some time* after the previous sequence point. And the function is called before the multiplication is done.

Comment: One more tip.  `++` and `--` can be fantastically useful operators.  But please don't use them when you don't need them.  Do you remember why you wrote `factorial(--number)` in the first place?  Do you see how `factorial(number-1)` does exactly what you need?  You do need to subtract 1 from `number`'s value before passing it to `factorial()` for the recursive call, but you don't need to store anything back into `number`.  Remember, `--` doesn't just mean "subtract 1".  It means, "subtract 1 and store back into".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your program suffers from *undefined behavior*.

In the first call to `factorial(5)`, where you have

```
return number * factorial(--number);
```

you imagine that this is going to compute

```
       5      * factorial(4);
```

But that's not guaranteed!
What if the compiler looks at it in a different order?
What it if works on the right-hand side first?
What if it first does the equivalent of:

```
temporary_result = factorial(--number);
```

and then does the multiplication:

```
return number * temporary_result;
```

If the compiler does it in that order, then `temporary_result` will be `factorial(4)`, and it'll return 4 times that, which won't be `5!`.  Basically, if the compiler does it in that order -- and it might! -- then `number` gets decremented "too soon".

You might not have imagined that the compiler could do things this way.
You might have imagined that the expression would always be "parsed left to right".
But those imaginations are not correct.
(See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31087537/why-does-a-b-have-the-same-behavior-as-a-b/31088592#31088592) for more discussion on order of evaluation.)

I said that the expression causes "undefined behavior", and this expression is a classic example.  What makes this expression undefined is that there's a little too much going on inside it.

The problem with the expression

```
return number * factorial(--number);
```

is that the variable `number` is having its value used within it, *and* that same variable `number` is also being modified within it.  And this pattern is, basically, poison.

Let's label the two spots where `number` appears, so that we can talk about them very clearly:

```
return number * factorial(--number);
       /* A */             /* B */
```

At spot A we take the value of the variable `number`.
At spot B we modify the value of the variable `number`.
But the question is, at spot A, do we get the "old" or the "new" value of `number`?
Do we get it before or after spot B has modified it?

And the answer, as I already said, is: *we don't know*.  There is no rule in C to tell us.

Again, you might have thought there was a rule about left-to-right evaluation, but there isn't.  Because there's no rule that says how an expression like this should be parsed, a compiler can do anything it wants.  It can parse it the "right" way, or the "wrong" way, or it can do something even more bizarre and unexpected.  (And, really, there's no "right" or "wrong" way to parse an undefined expression like this in the first place.)

The solution to this problem is: Don't do that!
Don't write expressions where one variable (like `number`) is both used and modified.
In this case, as you've already discovered, there's a simple fix:

```
return number * factorial(number - 1);
```

Now, we're not actually trying to modify the value of the variable `number` (as the expression `--number` did), we're just subtracting 1 from it before passing the smaller value off to the recursive call.
So now, we're not breaking the rule, we're not using and modifying `number` in the same expression.
We're just using its value twice, and that's fine.

For more (much more!) on the subject of undefined behavior in expressions like these, see [Why are these constructs using pre and post-increment undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior)

Comment: but it works if we used `number - 1 ` instead of `--number`

Comment: @IcanCode `number - 1`  does not change the value of `number` but `--number` does.

Comment: i am using  vscode  but i can t see any warnings or _undefined behavior_ alert

Comment: Maybe it just can't detect this undefined behavior in particular or maybe it expects you're doing it on purpose because you know what your compiler is going to do and you're not going to use a different compiler

Comment: @ash54321 Unfortunately, explicit warnings about undefined behavior are quite rare.  You have to know to avoid it by yourself.  The compiler won't aways warn you -- in fact in some cases it *can't* warn you.

Comment: Isn't this technically unspecified behavior, and still valid from the compilers view point. Number is only modified once in the expression, but the compiler is allowed to do it in any order it wants.

Comment: @jo-art It is undefined.  See citations at the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior).

Comment: @ash54321 Undefined behavior is kind of like jaywalking on a big highway.  You might get away with it, especially in the middle of the night when there's no traffic.  A policeman might give you a warning.  A policeman might give you a citation.  Or you might get run over by a semi.

Answer (score 0):

How to find the factorial of a number;

```
function factorial(n) {
    if(n == 0 || n == 1 ) {
        return 1;
    }else {
    return  n * factorial(n-1);  
    }
    //return newnum;
}
console.log(factorial(3))
```