# What are lvalues and rvalues?

Tags: c, rvalue, lvalue

I've heard the terms *lvalue* and *rvalue* come up when working with pointers.
However, I don't fully understand their meaning.

What are *lvalues* and *rvalues*?

<sub>Note: This is a question about C's lvalues and rvalues, not C++'s. It's also about their *functionality*, not their *naming*.</sub>

Comment: section 6.3.2.1 of the C11 standard draft covers this.

Comment: @dandan78 That's a C++ question.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I know. I was meaning for this to be a canonical dupe target.

Comment: Of possible help is [Please clarify the concept of lvalue and rvalue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983284/please-clarify-the-concept-of-lvalue-and-rvalue-here).

Comment: @WeatherVane Still not what I'm trying to accomplish. I want this to be generic.

Comment: @JL2210 I had a sneaking suspicion that may have been the case, but figured it wouldn't hurt to throw that out anyways.

Comment: There are no rvalues in C / the term is not used.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Then what's `&var`?

Comment: @JL2210 Never would've guessed since I see way too many similar questions that could've been answered with 30 seconds of googling. Anyhow, even though it's almost certainly not the best choice of dupe target, it is also tagged as C and does go into what they are.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala It's odd that section 6.3.2.1 doesn't ever use the term 'rvalue', but in the index of the C11 standard draft, the term 'rvalue' does come up, and points you to that section.  EDIT: actually, footnote 64 does make reference to "rvalue"

Comment: @ChristianGibbons it's a footnoote: *The name "lvalue" comes originally from the assignment expression E1 = E2, in which the left operand E1 is required to be a (modifiable) lvalue. It is perhaps better considered as representing an object "locator value". What is sometimes called "rvalue"" is in this International Standard described as the "value of an expression".*

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Sorry, you edited the comment as I was posting. I wonder why they decided to use "value of an expression" in the document and not "rvalue", but used the term "lvalue" rather than "locator value".

Comment: the "rvalue" is a nonsense category in that all lvalues, if they designate an object, can undergo lvalue conversion and become "rvalues".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got a longer answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52840265/918959), but basically [C11 draft n1570 6.3.2.1p1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1):

> An lvalue is an expression (with an object type other than void) that potentially designates an object [...]

[C11 n1570 Footnote 64](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note64):

> 64) The name **lvalue** comes originally from the assignment expression `E1 = E2`, in which the left operand `E1` is required to be a (modifiable) lvalue. It is perhaps better considered as representing an object **locator value**. What is sometimes called **rvalue** is in this International Standard described as the **value of an expression**. An obvious example of an lvalue is an identifier of an object. As a further example, if `E` is a unary expression that is a pointer to an object, `*E` is an lvalue that designates the object to which `E` points.

Not all lvalues are modifiable, i.e. can appear on the left side of an assignment. Examples of unmodifiable lvalues are those that

- have array type,
- have incomplete type
- are const-qualified
- `struct`s or `union`s that have `const`-qualified members either directly or recursively

An lvalue can be converted to a value of an expression through *lvalue conversion*. I.e. in

```
int a = 0, b = 1;
a = b;
```

both `a` and `b` are lvalues, as they both potentially - and actually - designate objects, but `b` undergoes lvalue conversion on the right-hand side of the assignment, and the value of the expression `b` after lvalue conversion is `1`.

*"Potentially designating an object"* means that given `int *p;`, `*p` designates an object of type `int` **iff** `p` points to an object of type `int` - but `*p` is an lvalue even if `p == NULL` or indeterminate.

Comment: There might be some value in also including the description of 'modifiable lvalues'.

Answer (score 1):

According to *the C Reference Manual (3rd Edition)*:

> An *lvalue* is an expression that refers to an object in such a way that
>   the object may be examined or altered. Only an lvalue expression may
>   be used on the left-hand side of an assignment. An expression that is
>   not an lvalue is sometimes called an *rvalue* because it can only appear
>   on the right-hand side of an assignment. An lvalue can have an
>   incomplete array type, but not *void*.

Comment: Can you give some background other than just copying from some "C reference manual"?

Comment: I figured there were lots of comments giving personal explanations. I elected to quote an accepted text.

Comment: I think the C standard is more accepted than some non-standardized manual. Could you at least provide a link to the material?

Comment: @JL2210 The text I referenced above is: __C: A Reference Manual 3th Edition_ by Samuel P. Harbison and Steele Jr., Guy L. Published by Prentice Hall. A search on Amazon shows it's now in its 5th Edition.