# Understanding post and pre increment with comma in between

Tags: c

Consider the below program

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
    int p = -8;
    int i = (p++, ++p);
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

I am unable to get why the output is -6.

`p++` would increment after the assignment statement is executed, `++p` will increment before thereby making -8 to -7.

How `i` is assigned -6?

Comment: The return value of `++p` is the value *after* increment, so -6

Comment: I think this is undefined behavior.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817517/do-parentheses-force-order-of-evaluation-and-make-an-undefined-expression-define

Comment: @AkshayLAradhya: again, no. `,` introduces a sequence point.

Answer (score 6):

Because for a comma operator `A,B` then `A` is done first then `B`, and `p++` increment the `p`, and `++p` also increment the `p`. [Operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Or think like this

```
int i = (p++, ++p);
```

is

```
p++;
int i = ++p;
```

Comment: So, that means even if it was p++, it is executed and the value is changed?

Comment: @user3767495 Think like this: after all, when `p++` is done, the `p` is incremented.

Answer (score 4):

The expression `(p++, ++p)` has a [*comma operator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). The comma operator evaluates its operand left-to-right and yields the result of the right most operand. Thus `i` gets the value `-6` (after `p++` and `++p` operations).

Answer (score 2):

as ptr_user7813604 said, you are using the comma operator which is a binary operator in c.
It evaluates it's first operand (in your case p++ increments p) and then discards the result (meaning p was incremented but not assigned to any variable) and then it evaluates the second operand (in your case ++p increments p) and returns this value and type. because the second operand is ++p so you receive the value after it was incremented, if the second operand was another p++ you would have assigned to i the value before it was incremented.

for additional information about the comma operator you can look up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator.