# what happen first when i do this kind of Increment in an assignment?

Tags: c

I have this expression:

```
B[i]=B[++i]*i;
```

In C this is undefined?

What happen first? is evaluated the right of the assignment symbol first, or the left?

Comment: It's undefined. And if you can't figure out what it means, why would you ever want to write code like that?

Comment: @BillLynch is question from a test... they ask about what is the output of a program, and the code have that expression. For me is undefined what happen, and i can I'm right, Thanks...

Comment: So, the test either expects UB as the answer, or it is rubbish. I give ten-to-one odds for the latter.

Comment: @exsnake -the only answer is "yes, it is undefined."

Comment: Also somewhat related to: [Assignment operator sequencing in C11 expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22616044/1708801) ... the defect report I cite in my answer gives a good framework for evaluating these type of constructs. If you can understand that proof it will help you understand a lot of these cases.

Comment: The order of evaluation is *unspecified*, so any expression that attempts to modify a variable more than once or tries to read from and modify a variable between sequence points will give different results for different platforms, compiler settings, etc.  The language definition specifically calls this out as *undefined behavior*, meaning the compiler isn't required to handle it any particular way.

Comment: @JohnBode well it is both unspecified and undefined behavior, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18260171/1708801) to the link duplicate. In this case they are orthogonal issues, the unspecified order of evaluation does not make it undefined, the multiple modifications do.

Answer (score 0):

It is undefined and can be evaluated in any order.

Comment: "Any order" guarantees more than is actually guaranteed, which is nothing.

Comment: @Deduplicator What does "any order" guarantee? To me it looks the same as nothing.

Comment: Any order guarantees that it will be evaluated in some order, but UB means it is simply non-sensical, and anything may happen.