# Why variable always print 0?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        j = j++;
    }
    printf("%d\n",j);

    return 0;
}
```

In the above program, I aspect `99` outputs of `j` variable. but It's always print `0`.

I don't understand, Why `j` always print `0`?

Comment: Try either `j++` or `j = j + 1`, *not* `j = j++`

Comment: Out of interest, is `j = ++j` now well-defined in C? It is in C++, from C++11.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: Thanks - good to know for those pub quizzes.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker no it didn't.

Comment: [See the footnote 84](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note84)

Comment: @Bathsheba another good to know for pub quiz ^

Comment: @AnttiHaapala : interesting, so there is a difference in this respect between C11 and C++11. A good write-up : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616044/assignment-operator-sequencing-in-c11-expressions/22616368#22616368 . Thanks ! It's good to know.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker [Jens' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22697426/918959) is the best. There is nothing else needed.

Comment: @Bathsheba : my apologies for misleading you ... I missed some important differences

Comment: @Jayesh The important line in your code, `j = j++`, is just about perfectly meaningless.  If you want to add 1 to `j`, you can use `j = j + 1` or `j++`.  But never try to mash the two together as `j = j++`, because the results are undefined.