# C++11: Unsequenced modification and access to variable (streams)

Tags: c++, c++11, clang

I recently wanted to get a better feeling for the return values of the ++i and the i++ operator. So I created this small program here:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    cout << "i++ " << i++ << " i " << i << endl;
    cout << "++j " << ++j << " j " << j << endl;
}
```

Now looking at the code I would expect that when I execute it I get the following result:

```
i++ 0 i 1
++j 1 j 1
```

Compiling the above snippet with llvm/clang 3.5 (Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.51)) yields the following warning:

```
main.cpp:8:23: warning: unsequenced modification and access to 'j'
      [-Wunsequenced]
    cout << "++j " << ++j << " j " << j << endl;
                      ^               ~
1 warning generated.
```

What does that mean in this context? The only [blog post I found](http://www.bionoren.com/blog/2013/07/unsequenced-modification-and-access/) was not so helpful since I can't imagine a reordering of the output somehow. 
What would the output of such a reordering look like?

There's also a couple of similar questions here. The only good question on the subject I found was this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066593/sequence-points-and-side-effects-quiet-change-in-c11/21066791). But I don't understand how this would create the compiler warning above.

Compiling the code from above with gcc 4.9 (the flag -std=c++11 was enabled) didn't show this warning at all.

Comment: Please make it stop, [make it stop](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XwRpss4yrec)

Comment: The order of the output is set in stone, but the order in which the values to be output are computed isn't.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @user657267 ! It's going to take me a while to get it. I feel that it has something to do in the way that streams are handled: Do you have a pointer for me in this direction? Btw: I can understand your frustration... As soon as Visual Studio C++11/17 support becomes more common there's going to be an increased number of similar questions...